# When I try to send two files in a html form, request is always pending

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to send two files/images in a form but request is stalled. It is always pending. In my local VM Box it works but on server the problem that i mentioned is occurred. I checked out php version, jQuery version and they are all same with my local. What is the problem?

EDIT 1: Here is form:

```
<form method="POST" id="package-create-form" action="/admin/packages/pack">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="image" class="bold">IMAGE</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="map-image" class="bold">MAP IMAGE</label>
       <input type="file" class="form-control" id="map-image" name="map_image">
    </div>
    <div class="text-right">
       <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="cancel-button"
           data-href="/admin/packages/pack"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>Back</button>
       <button type="submit" id="store-btn2"
           class="btn btn-primary">Forward<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
       </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: PHP error log please...

Comment: Also code if possible

Comment: check file permission ,what do you mean by pending & salled?

Comment: you need to check your response time, max  file size to be allow to upload in .ini and keep alive time in apache.

Comment: @RendyEkoPrastiyo i checked out logs and there is nothing about this. I tried again now and checked logs. I logged daily and there is no log file for today.

Comment: @akkatracker i added the form EDIT1. Do you want php and jquery codes? I use jQuery.form by malsup

Comment: @madalinivascu file permissions are ok. There is no problem when trying 1 file. I mean pending. It is pending, no response could be taken.

Comment: @AfshanShujat There is no response so request is finished after long time waiting (about 12 min). Max file size also okay because i can upload bigger file with form (just 1 file :) )

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to write correct enctype for form.
This is `enctype="multipart/form-data"` for images. It's required
And second one, if you'd like to upload more than one image, you have to use tag `multiple` in your `input type="file"`.
To sum up:
`<form method="POST" id="package-create-form" action="/admin/packages/pack" enctype="multipart/form-data">`
and
`<input type="file" class="form-control" id="map-image" name="map_image" multiple>`
[More about enctype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4526286/6066986)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First, I added enctype="multipart/form-data" on my previous tries. It changes nothing. Second, multiple tag is necessary when you want to upload multiple files in an input. On the contrary, i want to upload two files on two different inputs.

Comment: I got it, try to get your files with $_FILES on your backend (php script) side, `print_r($_FILES)`. And you have to see your images (their data(names, folder path and size).

Comment: The form could not to be sent to back-end. I change the action with http://google.com but result is same. So the request is stucked between ajax request and back-end and never reach to url. It is very very mysterious situation for me.

Comment: Does your backend script exists on http(s)://your_url/admin/packages/pack ?
Are you sure that you wrote path correctly? Maybe try to create test file, like test.php on /admin/packages/test.php and than send your form there?

Comment: Yes it does. I will try test again.